# ArcView (ArcGIS) AVL file format to Matlab mat file format

Tags: matlab, mat

I have a file that is in AVL file format from a program called ArcGIS (formerly ArcView) that I need to convert to a mat file. It contains data I need to play back. Can anybody suggest a simple way to convert the file? I have done quite a bit of searching, and it seems the AVL is not a binary, aka it is a text format, which means I could write a program to convert it, but only if I also knew the corresponding matlab MAT file format. Moreover, this could take quite a while to do, and I need to file to be converted quickly so I can use the data.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "only if I knew the matlab MAT file format". A `mat` file can contain any number of variables saved from your MATLAB workspace, if you need one you must have some MATLAB code that reads those specific variables and does something with them, so don't you know what it needs to contain? If you don't, we certainly won't.

Comment: A mat file is a certain file format. AVL is a different file format. I needed to convert them. I found a program that would do it for me anyway. A lot of work to get at some engine data  if you ask me.